# How to create btree index with n=3 in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, b-tree, database-indexes

I have created a btree using:

```
CREATE INDEX indexname ON students USING btree
(id);
```

But I wanted to create a tree with n=3. I am not sure where insert the n value in postgresql:

```
CREATE INDEX indexname ON students USING btree(n=3) 
(id);
```

Not Working.

Comment: What is that `n=3` supposed to do?

Comment: The number of values in one node

Comment: No idea what that should mean. Anyways, there is no such option. If you want more than one column in the index, then just specify them  `on students (id, firstname)` The internals of the Postgres B-Tree implementation are documented here: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/backend/access/nbtree

Comment: @Casper What do you mean by a "node"? Please be verbose and specific.

Comment: If n=3 such that every children can have utmost n-1 = 2 keys. If we create b-tree using the above command I am not sure how many keys can be stored in one node. What if I want my each node in the tree contain certain keys. I am not sure if it is possible to modify in Postgresql or not.

Comment: Let's call it the degree of tree

Comment: The syntax would be `CREATE INDEX ... ON ... USING ... WITH ( opts )` but I'm not sure of an option for node size or if it even makes sense within Postgres's btree implementation (it could be dynamic for all I know), only aware of `fillfactor` and `deduplicate_items`. (e.g. https://grep.app/search?q=USING%20btree%20%5C%28.%2A%5C%29%20WITH&regexp=true)